# PowerShell Script Consumes All Memory & Crashes Server

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that gets a list of files in a folder and all its subfolders, then reads them one by one checking for certain invalid values in each file.  This script has run fine for many years on a Windows Server 2008 machine with 8gb of memory.  Sorry, I don't remember the version of PS that was running then, but assume it was 3.0.

This server was recently upgraded to Windows Server 2012 R2, added an addtional 8gb of memory and is running PSVersion 4.0.  Ever since the upgrade, the script crashes the server by eating more and more memory until it is all exhausted.  There are usually about 300,000+ files to examine each time the script is run, ranging in size from a few KB each up to around 300mb each.  This is the warning error I see in Event Viewer after the crash and reboot:

> Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. The
> following programs consumed the most virtual memory: powershell.exe
> (5964) consumed **66568437760 bytes**, splunkd.exe (1900) consumed
> 263499776 bytes, and svchost.exe (1852) consumed 83922944 bytes.

What could be the difference between PS 3.0 and 4.0 that could cause this, or is it something with the OS?

As for these old OS versions, this is a legacy server that will be going away by the end of the year, but I have to keep it running for now.  We only upgraded to 2012 as Win 2008 is considered a big security risk and the rest of the old software won't run on anything above Win 2012.

Thanks for any help with this issue.

Comment: If you can, can you include the code in the post?

Comment: seeing the code will be needed to give any specific advice. [*grin*] ///// however, there are a few things that can help ... [1] get your list of files as JUST the full file names. G-CI adds a great deal of info to each `fileinfo` object. [2] the `Select-String` cmdlet will accept a file name & _quickly_ load that file - apparently it's quicker than `Get-Content`. [3] using the pipeline will reduce RAM use. [4] explicitly triggering garbage collection can sometimes reduce RAM use.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but I got this fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but I got this fixed.
The first thing I tried was to use [System.GC]::Collect().  I read so much about this and was amazed at all the differing information people were providing whether to use this or not.  In the if loop, I kept a counter of files read and would call Collect every 1000 files.  Unfortunately, this had no effect at all.
I then just upgraded PowerShell to v5.1 from this link:
https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/F/5/6F5FF66C-6775-42B0-86C4-47D41F2DA187/Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu
Now everything works as before.